# How do you specify a column by it's native name in an SQL Selection?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am writing an application with Spring 4 and Hibernate 5.1. I need to be able to interoperate with a legacy system that saves SQL queries using the native table and column names. I need to be able to add a Selection object to my Tuple query which uses the original column name rather then the entity field name.

I tried doing this using Hibernate with Projections.sqlProjection(column_name... and that sort of worked, but other issues are preventing me from continuing in this direction.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public List<Object[]> testQuery() {

    Class<?> rootClass = getEntityClassByTable("pm_project");

    List<String> columnList = new ArrayList<>();
    columnList.add("pm_project.pm_project_id");
    columnList.add("pm_project.pm_project_name");
    columnList.add("pm_project.pm_project_title");
    columnList.add("pm_project.parent_id");
    columnList.add("pm_project.pm_project_from_date");

    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();
    Root<?> root = query.from(rootClass);
    List<Selection> selectionList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String column : columnList) {
            Selection s = nativeSelection(column);
            selectionList.add(s);
    }
    query.multiselect(selectionList.toArray());

    List<Tuple> resultList = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    return resultList;
}
```

I need 'NativeSelection', something that produces a Selection for a native column name, not an entity attribute name. It would be really good if it took any sql that could be a field, because some JSON_VALUE fields might pop up.

The values of the native sql are dynamic, and I am not receiving a full SQL, only column and table names, with possible JSON_VALUE calls. I would very much like not to have to generate native sql, as I want to leverage other JPA features in my query.

Comment: use native query https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/query-native/Native.html

Comment: As I said in the original text: "I would very much like not to have to generate native sql, as I want to leverage other JPA features in my query." The point of this is to create a tuple query with variable Selections using native names, and possible with using native sql as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using native query then no need to specify entity attribute names. All you have to do is to set the value of the nativeQuery attribute to true and define the native SQL query in the value attribute of the annotation

```
@Query(
  value = "SELECT * FROM pm_project p WHERE p.pm_project_id= 1", 
  nativeQuery = true)
Collection<Project> findProjectById();
```

Comment: As I said in the original text: "I would very much like not to have to generate native sql, as I want to leverage other JPA features in my query." The point of this is to create a tuple query with variable Selections using native names, and possible with using native sql as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without using native query by simple JPA

```
List<Project> findAllByProjectId(Integer id);
```

Comment: I need something that works with any field, not just the id.